# c++ templates policy with arguments

Tags: c++, class, templates, policy

I am new to this. I am creating a class with policies say:

```
template <typename T,
          typename P1 = Policy1<T>,
          typename P2 = Policy2<T> >

{
    ...
}
```

The problem I have is that some of the policies have arguments, and when they are compile time it is ok

```
template <typename T,
          typename P1 = Policy1<T, size_t N>,
          typename P2 = Policy2<T> >
```

but when they are runtime I am not sure what is the best way to provide the policy class object ... or this is no longer a policy pattern?

Comment: Give us an example of how you would like to do it at runtime.

Comment: The standard library solves this by accepting initializers in the constructor. E.g. for custom comparators or allocators.

Comment: say the policy class have a constructor that accepts argument and you passing an object to your class

Comment: @gsf So you already know how to do it...?

Comment: @sehe could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @0x499602D2, maybe, but this does not mean I know the best way to do it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a factory for the policy :) **EDIT** See added below

Ooor you can do as the standard library does:

```
#include <string>

struct DummyPolicy { };

template <typename>
struct Policy1 { Policy1(int, std::string) { } };

template <typename T,
          typename P1 = Policy1<T> >
struct X 
{
     X(P1 p1 = {}) : _policy1(std::move(p1)) { }

   private:
     P1 _policy1;
};
```

And use it

```
int main()
{
     X<int, DummyPolicy> no_questions_asked;
     X<int> use_params({42, "hello world"});
}
```

With C++03 or explicit constructors obviously spell it out:

```
     X<int> use_params(Policy1<int>(42, "hello world"));
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305fa1c11b570279)**

---

## Update: Factories

Here's an update showing the factory approach:

```
#include <string>

namespace details
{
    template <typename PolicyImpl>
        struct PolicyFactory
        {
            static PolicyImpl Create() {
                return {};
            }
        };
}

template <typename>
struct Policy2 { Policy2(double) { } };

template <typename T,
          typename P1 = Policy2<T> >
struct X 
{
    X()      : _policy1(details::PolicyFactory<P1>::Create()) {}
    X(P1 p1) : _policy1(std::move(p1)) { }

  private:
    P1 _policy1;
};

///// supply a factor, possibly local to a TU:

namespace details
{
    template <typename T>
        struct PolicyFactory<Policy2<T> > {
            static Policy2<T> Create() { 
                return Policy2<T>(3.14);
            }
        };
}

int main()
{
     // with a factory:
     X<std::string, Policy2<std::string> > no_params_because_of_factory;
}
```

See it *[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/432cc7369209eab7)**

Note that

- I prefer the constructor pass-in approach
- The factory is technically a *trait* class

Comment: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305fa1c11b570279)**

Comment: @gsf added the factory idea for completeness.

Comment: thanks, seems logical, I was just not sure this is the best way to go

Answer (score 5):

Policies in templates are meant to customize a class at compile time, not at run time (policies shape the **type** of the instance, and you cannot decide types at run time in C++).

The parallel at run time is normally called "dependency injection" and you do it for example by passing already constructed objects to which the instance will delegate operations.